# I was trying to scrape data from Monster Job using Beautiful Soup But I did not manage to get any job cards

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image]

This is my code as below.
I inspected the page and found the "div" tag and "class" for all the job cards.
However, there is no output.
When I preview my code on Postman, none of the job cards are shown.

```
def get_url(position, location):
    position = position.replace(" ", "%20")
    location = location.replace(" ", "%20")
    template = "https://www.monster.com.my/srp/results?query={}&locations={}"
    url = template.format(position, location)
    return url 

url = get_url("Python Developers", "Kuala Lumpur")
print(url)


headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")

# Get job info of all cards
cards = soup.find("div", "card-panel apply-panel job-apply-card")
print(cards)
output --> None
```

May I know how to resolve this?
If Selenium is involved in this web scraping, how do I get the job details?

Comment: The page data is dynamically loaded by javascript, so it's not visible for requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0",
    "Referer": "https://www.monster.com.my/"
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        req.head('https://www.monster.com.my/')
        for item in range(0, 100, 25):
            params = {
                "start": item,
                "sort": "1",
                "limit": "25",
                "query": "Python Developers",
                "locations": "Kuala Lumpur",
                "searchId": "4a4b18ed-d3f1-4673-b371-0231d4bcc00a"
            }
            r = req.get(url, params=params)
            for item in r.json()['jobSearchResponse']['data']:
                # or print item.keys() and pickup what you need.
                print(item.get('title', 'N/A'))


main('https://www.monster.com.my/middleware/jobsearch')
```